# To use or not to use SSL? Why use SSL always?

Tags: ssl, https, security

The argument for using SSL is to prevent some malicious user who has gone through the pains of snooping your traffic being able to read your traffic. So while it may make sense if you are using an unsecured wireless (non WPA2) network to use SSL when logging on to your bank account or giving your credit card number, I find it difficult to see it's neccessaity in more common business cases.

Why even bother with SSL?  (when your client is not going to be on an unsecured wireless network)

The only way someone can snoop your particular HTTP connections and data therein is if they have admin access to your router (and then only if there is some facility to monitor/copy traffic), installed some tool on your machine (a key logger of course would by pass SSL anyway) or they monitor you at the ISP (for which a warrant is required in most jurisdictions).

**Update Warning** Some jurisdictions are not as free as you may think, particularly the 1st and 2nd world, e.g. in the UK, government may soon not require a warrant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_Data_Bill_2008 which will probably entail the ability to read websites as they were historically (i.e. decrypt SSL) and the US's "Patriot Act" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Patriot_Act#Title_II:_Surveillance_procedures

Furthermore:

- Accepting SSL connections server side adds significant load as the establishing of a connection is processor intensive (during the generation of secret keys).
- Publicly trusted SSL certificates have to be purchased from a 3rd Party periodically

**UPDATE:** I am actually using SSL, though I thought it worthwhile to ask the question anyway. Certainly I think there are time SSL is not necessary. Maybe this could be turned into a community wiki of the pros and cons of SSL? If so how?

There seems to be commonly occurring myth in the answers below: "anyone between you and the server can eavesdrop on you"...

- This is not not possible on the Internet as the low level TCP routers only forward packets where they have to go and even in the same session can be routed through different routes, and no one can look at these packets except in extreme cases - technically or lawfully.
- As for someone at the ISP looking at your traffic I wonder why they would signal you out and look at the 'so important data' which no doubt is boring to them, this is also illegal without a warrant.

  On your LAN (except wireless) unless you are using a dinosaur Hub which broadcasts every packet there is no way listen on someone else's traffic - this is not possible because the hardware simply does not send the packets to you even if you have your network card in promiscuous mode and are using a sniffing tool such as Snort or Wireshark.

Passive ARP poisoning is one way to  listen in but has to be done internally and should be picked up as name conflicts etc. start occuring and often the default gateway would be static so would be v. difficult cause the default gateway will be on before you.

Comment: SSL is *not* computationally intensive. And the connection can be sniffed anywhere along its route, from any machine that can see the traffic. It does not have to be a router. SSL certificates are also very cheap.

Comment: I sincerely hope you don't develop e-commerce systems with that kind of attitude.

Comment: You do realize that there are other machines between the user and the server, yes? The CPU cost of SSL is negligent compared to the possibility of a breach, and many other companies require encrypted channels to merely do business with them.

Comment: @In silico: I guess e-commerce would fall under the category of entering ones credit card number on an unsecured network as you dont know what the client is using. I am talking more apps/sites for limited client base where you can require they are not using an unsecured wireless network. Was this not clear above? maybe I should clarify.

Comment: @GregS and birrye. The connection route is pretty direct - any modern router (actually a switch) is intelligent enough to only send the packets down the channel they need to go, i.e. they are not broadcast to other machines. Have you ever tried sniffing traffic of another machine? It's no piece of cake and usually requires some intervention on the network.

Comment: @Mrk Mnl: Do you control **every** link from the client to your server? If not, use SSL. A single link that is out of your hands is a place where an eavesdropper can listen.

Comment: @Mrk - ARP poisoning makes this pretty straightforward, and it takes some pretty advanced gear to prevent it. And yes I have successfully MITM'd machines on a well set-up corporate network, for pentesting purposes.

Comment: @Mrk Mnl: What I meant was that when it comes to sensitive information, your attitude of "SSL is too expensive" is unethical and irresponsible. When you have sensitive information in your hands, you must do everything you can to secure it. You say that you don't see its worth in "common business cases", but "common business cases" often involve sensitive information (addresses, phone numbers, email messages, trade secrets, etc). A business has much to lose in a breach of data integrity.

Comment: @Mrk Mnl: Are you serious?  Are you actually completely discounting the possibility that someone might be willing to go to the effort of, say, hacking a system?

Comment: SSL is of course crackable if you have the resources (a super computer, through distributed computing or a lot of patience) all you have to do is collect coherent data which is harder than you think.

Comment: This is Fallacy of Distribute Computing number four. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing / As it turns out: switches tend to fail open; DNS, ARP, etc., are not secure; vulnerabilities are so common they are not news and, of course, there is good old fashioned misconfiguration. Oh, did you see recently that a large proportion of internet traffic apparently unexpectedly went via China for a short while?

Comment: Do you honestly think there are 'baddies' in China who are going to sift through the taffic and find Mr Smith's GET request on September 14 of any use?

Comment: Ironically the Fallacy of Distribute Computing number four is applicable to those who believe SSL secures the network :)

Comment: @Mrk Mni: You clearly do not understand what SSL does. It protects the connection between me and the machine I'm talking to. No more, no less. It makes **that connection** secure, point-to-point. Of course if your corporate network is insecure then you're wasting your time, but that's not a reason not to secure the public-internet bit. It's like saying "once a burglar is in my house nothing is secure so I won't lock the front door". Your insurance company would probably not pay out if you were burgled.

Comment: @Mrk Mnl: By the way, the "baddies in China" argument is a straw man and you know it. There are a bazillion ways someone on the network can do naughty things and there is a lot of information floating around that is very valuable: names, addresses, phone numbers, social security numbers in the US, internal corporate memos, sales strategy meeting notes, etc, etc. If your application doesn't send **any** valuable information around then what, exactly, does it do?

Comment: @Mrk Mnl: I'd also point out that the "unlawful" bit is moot. Again, burglary is unlawful but that doesn't mean it never happens.

Comment: Im not talking about a particular application. I know exactly what SSL does. I guess I think security has got blown out of proportion from paranoia. For example (im glad you mention it): I find names, address, phone numbers memos etc. not be a sufficient reason use SSL. Sure one could by breaking the law and digging these details from network traffic get them (which is not trivial as I have tried to point out)... but why not use the phone book! :) Really corporations and people who make a living out spreading fear of network breaches have gone over the top.

Comment: The analogy of tapping a phone line strikes me - should we encrypt our voice conversations too? Maybe there is market for that :)

Comment: @Mrk Mnl: I take your point, and that is exactly what security is all about: balancing the cost of security against the value of the information being secured. If you are certain that none of the information you send is valuable (and you are sure that the customer thinks the same thing) then don't bother with security. For example, I don't bother using SSL to browse StackOverflow because I'm not sending any secrets. I wouldn't use Skype to discuss confidential information precisely because it is an unsecured connection with a man-in-the-middle who can listen as much as they want.

Comment: Remember the old days of dumpster diving when people sifted through piles of trash looking for something they could exploit?  Sifting through web traffic is no different, and is not difficult for someone who knows what he's doing.

Comment: Mrk, it sounds like you've already decided to not use SSL. As you can see, most of us strongly disagree. Perhaps you should ask somebody else at your business, or your clients, if they would be OK with all the information that your application uses being sent in the clear and available to anybody who decides to invest a rather small amount of effort.

Comment: Im just play devil's advocate. I am not talking about a particular system - it is a generic question. It is not small amount of effort to get this information - I am familiar with tools of the pen-testing trade.  Yeah I guess its ultimately up to how sensitive you/client thinks the information is, though knowing how the this information would be got at would help one make a more informed decision.

Comment: @Mrk: "Do you honestly think there are 'baddies' in China who are going to sift through the taffic and find Mr Smith's GET request on September 14 of any use?"  THEY ALREADY HAVE - recall the GMail account hacking that occurred a year or so ago.  Google's response? Implement SSL for GMail connections, and push users to make it the default connection.  Google originally claimed they didn't implement SSL for compute cost reasons, but when somebody took the time to hack GMail accounts over unsecured TCPIP, compute cost was suddenly no longer an issue.

Comment: @Mrk Mnl: "(Facebook doesn't)": Uhh, [Facebook supports https](https://login.facebook.com/).

Comment: Ultimately it is not possible to snoop someone elses traffic unless you are on their LAN (unless you are the ISP), and if it can be done internally there would no doubt be an easier way to get at it then MITM type snooping, I bet the amount of geninue such efforts internally to snoop network traffic worldwide is almost nil. The biggest snoopers are probably governments where they can be the MINTM or access you ISP but then you shouldnt have to worry unless you are targeted by the government.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: "I don't bother using SSL to browse StackOverflow because I'm not sending any secrets. I wouldn't use Skype to discuss confidential information precisely because it is an unsecured connectio". 1) Thats the mindset im talking about! Of course you wouldnt use SSL on SO because what you say is published for the world to see anyway (optimised for search engines)!!! 2) Skype has better encryption than SSL - I happen to know.

Comment: All I have to do is compromise a router and I can [selectively pick up any traffic flows passing through it that I want, and send them right back to my desktop](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/7600/ios/15S/configuration/guide/span.html). It's not trivial to compromise a router on the Internet backbone, but it has been done before and certainly it will happen again.

Answer (score 43):

SSL should be used anywhere where you are communicating information that should not be public.  It is a very dangerous assumption to believe that no-one is listening to traffic between your computer and the remote server.

All someone needs to do to snoop traffic is be on your network - they don't need admin access to your router.  Without using SSL for sensitive communications, a single machine with a virus on a coworkers computer is all that is needed for stealing your identity.

The ISP also has access to all network traffic - how much do you trust their techies?

> Dear User,
>
> We've decided against
> encrypting our internet traffic
> because we just don't think it's
> important.  We decided that it's
> really too hard to monitor internet
> traffic, so if anyone really is
> prepared to go to that effort, well
> they deserve all the data they can get
> their hands on. If you're using an old
> style of router, have corrupt IT
> staff and/or co-workers, or someone
> just doesn't like you and decides to
> steal your data, we accept no
> liability.
>
> We advise against you telling anyone about our decision, as this will direct unwanted attention to our IP traffic.
>
> Kindest Regards,
>
> *Good Enough Programming*
>
> **Disclaimer:** If you are a hacker and stumbled across this message while monitoring IP traffic, we politely point out that what you are doing is illegal, and request that you pretend you never saw it.

Comment: Personal info available in the phone directory is not "very dangerous" if leaked. The info is not made public - it is private data that is maliciously and illegally got with difficulty - being on the network is not all that is required (read above). A virus on their machine could bypass SSL anway by getting the info before it is encrypted. I trust the techies couldnt care less about the boring corporate data which would be a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Im not a lawyer but I dont think one could get sued for negligence in this case, could the Post Office be sued for the theft of mail or the Telephone carrier sued if someone wiretapped their lines? Rather the hacker would be charged for breaching the Cyber Criminal Act.

Comment: That is the point im trying to make: its not left out in the open! There are these fears by people who are unfamiliar with snooping that anyone on the Internet can easily snoop anothers traffic - it is actually practically impossible to a level - but then when they can no matter if you are using SSL or not they will be able to read it.

Comment: My grudge against using SSL by default is it is profiteering on spreading mythical fears.

Comment: It is a pity you have deleted your arguments, they are certainly valid and the majority feel the same as you, I like a good argument and am argumentative, I am just playing devils advocate for the sake of the argument. No doubt the many views this question gets is people wanting to see both sides of the argument, even though the answer may not be conclusive it does help one!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that using, say, WPA2 only secures the connection between your computer and the router. There is a large piece of unsecured network between the router and the destination - that's the design of the internet. You don't know who is along the path and there could be any number of malicious (or just nosey) listeners out there. They may not even be in your jurisdiction so preventing eavesdropping may well be impossible.

SSL gives you an encrypted tunnel all the way to the other end.

If you're talking about a small company LAN where no traffic leaves the internal network then sure, don't bother with SSL if you don't want to. But if anything sensitive goes across the internet then you really want to use SSL to stop anyone seeing it. It's all about how important the information is.

One thing to be aware of is that many websites use cookies to remember login information. If those cookies go across the internet in the clear then it is fairly trivial to hijack the session - think FireSheep. Thus, you need to be very careful about what you consider to be "sensitive" information. Given that many business applications are moving to remote servers (I think the young'uns call it "the cloud") this is not a minor issue.

Long story short, use SSL if there is anything you don't want anyone else to see going across a network that is not entirely in your control.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, even in a small company LAN you still want SSL. That prevents a disgruntled (or future-disgruntled) employee from sniffing the network and obtaining information that they shouldn't have. They don't even need admin access - there are plenty of network-watching tools out there. They're good for security monitoring!

Answer (score 3):

SSL provides authentication and encryption.

It *is* somewhat difficult to MITM an unencrypted connection, but not so hard on the unencrypted wireless network you gave as an example. Any network that allows you to ARP spoof (many switched wired networks) allows you to MITM as well. But you're forgetting about every router along the way. Remember a few months back when a (hopefully) poorly configured router in China routed a significant, though small in relative terms, portion of Internet traffic? They could've seen your plaintext. So can other customers on a cable network, and so on.

But SSL also provides authentication. If I get the private key to a valid SSL cert from you, I'm damn confident that you are who you say you are - doubly so if it's a competent CA.

But the bigger concern is - you don't quite seem to understand SSL, so I'd advise you against making a decision one way or the other by yourself - at least until you read more. SSL does **not** require you to generate a new key every request, and in fact would not work if it did. Furthermore, any reasonably-recent computer can handle thousands of SSL requests simultaneously - the algorithms are very fast. Furthermore you can use encryption accelerators that offload the work to a dedicated piece of hardware.

If you think you **might** need to use SSL to secure some data, and often if you don't, there are almost no reasons to avoid it. Yes there is some expenditure involved but any data of consequence is worth the $300/yr.

**EDIT** I read your comment - this is a client app? The solution in your case is probably to use self-signed keys, and you can distribute the public key with the app. This allows you to encrypt and verify that you're talking to who you should be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that every website needs SSL, if you do then use it, but there are cases where you want to be able to authenticate user without having to use SSL.

I've created (javascript->perl) single use random hash authentication for just this purpose.

http://www.furiousgryphon.com/jauthenticatedemo.html

https://github.com/thomasoeser/jAuthenticate

Comment: One of the reasons to use SSL is that the server's certificate offers the user some assurance of the identity of the server. You don't want to hand over your password or other credentials to a spoofed server, after all.

Comment: I think these sort of issues are really contingent on threat risk and mitigation strategies. What I mean by that is if you set up a site that only a handful of people use and you don't store sensitive information then it can be overkill to use SSL. That being said, if you 're running a commercial web site then get SSL. If you have a hobby website or experimental website then use something like jAuthenticate.

Answer (score -1):

One of the things most people here are forgetting to address is what do you consider sensitive data? What one person considers boring useless data may be considered highly confidential by someone else, or vice versa. So what are you going to do? Use SSL on all the data to play it safe so that you don't get sued? Get real. Take a chat program for example. Most would agree that encrypting the username and password would be important, but what about the chat text itself? Most chat is mundane stuff and eliminating SSL will provide better performance. Personally, I would let the end user decide what is important and then provide SSL for only those types of information that they feel needs to be encrypted. That's what Google does with Gmail. You have the choice of using SSL or not.

Comment: Not anymore. Now it is on by default. I am not sure if it can be turned off. Same for facebook.